# CSS property to pad text inside of div

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to give a `div` element some padding INSIDE its border? For example, currently all the text inside my main `div` element goes right to the edge of the element's border. I'd like, as a general rule on this site, to have at least 10 to 20 px of space between the text and the border.

Here's a screen shot to illustrate what I currently have:

[image]

Comment: add the padding to the elements inside of the div

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I see a lot of answers here that have you subtracting from the width of the div and/or using box-sizing, but all you need to do is apply the padding the child elements of the div in question. So, for example, if you have some markup like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <p id="text">Find Agents</p>
</div>
```

All you need to do is apply this CSS:

```
#text {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing the difference: https://jsfiddle.net/CHCVF/2/

Or, better yet, if you have multiple elements and don't feel like giving them all the same class, you can do something like this:

```
.container * {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Which will select all of the child elements and assign them the padding you want. Here is a fiddle of that in action: https://jsfiddle.net/CHCVF/3/

Comment: This is what I did - created a div called `contentContainer` and gave that a padding of 20px. thx

Comment: @NealR No problem, glad you figured it out

Comment: `.container *` does not work if you have multiple containers within it. All the inner containers will also get the padding which might be undesirable.

Comment: This gonna apply padding for everything...this is a not good answer... Need to use  box-sizing: border-box; with padding to apply padding for particular div.

Answer (score 56):

The CSS property you are looking for is padding.
The problem with padding is that it adds to the width of the original element, so if you have a div with a width of 300px, and add 10px of padding to it, the width will now be 320px (10px on the left and 10px on the right).

To prevent this you can add box-sizing: border-box; to the div, this makes it maintain the designated width, even if you add padding.
So your CSS would look like this:

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

you can read more about box-sizing and it's overall browser support here:

https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Answer (score 6):

Just use `div { padding: 20px; }` and substract `40px` from your original `div` width.

Like Philip Wills pointed out, you can also use `box-sizing` instead of substracting `40px`:

```
div {
    padding: 20px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The `-moz-box-sizing` is for Firefox.

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle too?

Comment: or add box-sizing: border-box... (instead of subtracting 40)

Comment: Only problem w/this solution is that it blows up my nav bar. Had to create a separate div container around the main div and simply give that a padding of 20px. thanks though, didn't know about border-box.

Answer (score 1):

Padding is a way to add kind of a margin inside the Div.
Just Use

```
div { padding-left: 20px; }
```

And to mantain the size, you would have to -20px from the original width of the Div.